# Files for deploying a Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, deployment

I'm currently making a simple calculator using C++ and Qt. But what do I need to deploy it so that it can run on other computers? Which Qt dll files do I need to include and how? I don't know anything about deployment and that's why I need help.

Comment: Google? - https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place Qt DLLs along the release version of your executable. These are QtCore4.dll, QtGui4.dll and possibly the ones for other modules that you have used. These dll files are in your installed Qt Directory in bin folder. You should also place msvcr100.dll and msvcp100.dll in case you are using MSVS2010. If you are using plugins you should place their dll in a folder named "plugins" beside youe exe. In case of using icons and images you should ship their dlls like qico4.dll and qsvg4.dll in a folder named "imageformats".

Answer (score 1):

I think this question has already been answered before, but just in case I will share this snippet that I used in a Qt project file for this purpose.

For this example I assumed that you have some environment variables QTBASE and QTVER to appropriate values of where and which Qt you installed, and I assumed that you must have `cp` and `bash` and `mkdir`. Or you can change these commands to use whatever you normally use to copy files and make directories.

Also notice the path of the `qwindows.dll`. It is `plugins/platforms/qwindows.dll` in the distribution (at least in my installation) but `platforms/qwindows.dll` in the deployment copy. At least this is the only way I could get it to work. I don't remember seeing this mentioned in the documentation, but maybe I missed something.

```
#
# Copy Qt dependencies
#
system("cp -vuL %QTBASE%/%QTVER%/mingw48_32/bin/Qt5Core.dll" "$$OUT_PWD")
system("cp -vuL %QTBASE%/%QTVER%/mingw48_32/bin/Qt5Gui.dll" "$$OUT_PWD")
system("cp -vuL %QTBASE%/%QTVER%/mingw48_32/bin/Qt5Widgets.dll" "$$OUT_PWD")
system("cp -vuL %QTBASE%/%QTVER%/mingw48_32/bin/libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll" "$$OUT_PWD")
system("cp -vuL %QTBASE%/%QTVER%/mingw48_32/bin/libstdc++-6.dll" "$$OUT_PWD")
system("cp -vuL %QTBASE%/%QTVER%/mingw48_32/bin/libwinpthread-1.dll" "$$OUT_PWD")
system("cp -vuL %QTBASE%/%QTVER%/mingw48_32/bin/icudt51.dll" "$$OUT_PWD")
system("cp -vuL %QTBASE%/%QTVER%/mingw48_32/bin/icuin51.dll" "$$OUT_PWD")
system("cp -vuL %QTBASE%/%QTVER%/mingw48_32/bin/icuuc51.dll" "$$OUT_PWD")
system("bash -c \"mkdir -p $$OUT_PWD/plugins\"")
system("bash -c \"mkdir -p $$OUT_PWD/platforms\"")
system("cp -vuL %QTBASE%/%QTVER%/mingw48_32/plugins/platforms/qwindows.dll" "$$OUT_PWD/platforms/")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you used QT Creator, than you just have to ship QT DLLs with the executable. That means, the DLLs have to be located in the same folder as the executable. Usually the program should tell you what DLLs it needs. Just try to start your exe on a computer without QT, you'll see what I mean.

If you used Microsoft Visual Studio instead, you also have to install Visual C++ Redistributable on the target computer.